# I am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson" error even though it is defined in my classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I'm trying to parse some JSON object strings that I'm getting using gson-1.6.jar  I have placed it in the same location as my other .jars and have added it to my buildpath in eclipse.

The other libraries worked fine when I added them and I can use them without any issues, but when I try to create the JSON object, I get the titular error. I've looked through the other questions with this error, but I couldn't find a solution that didn't involve something that I've tried or something unrelated.

I import it near the top using:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Then use it later in a static function like so:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
```

Here is my eclipse generated classpath file [Path] substituted for actual path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre6">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v5.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="[Path]/jabbabase-ws-jwsdp-client-2.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="[Path]/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="[Path]/gson-1.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

as well as my build path window:
[image: Build Path Screen]

I'm a little lost at this point.  I've tried Google and the posts basically just say to add to your build path.  Anybody have any ideas?

Edit: More Info

The code referencing com.google.gson.GSON is used as a bean by a jsp.  This function is called from the jsp and the error occurs as soon as the function is executed. The first line in the function is:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
```

It seems to compile and deploy fine, but when it is executed, I get the error message.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: Through the eclipse IDE, as a jsp with the java file being used as a bean

Comment: in my case I added gson jar in server path and it worked, i am using weblogic

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In case of a JSP/Servlet webapplication, you just need to drop 3rd party JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. If the project is a *Dynamic Web Project*, then Eclipse will automatically take care about setting the buildpath right as well. You do **not** need to fiddle with Eclipse buildpath. Don't forget to undo it all.

Comment: I actually have the file there as well, but still no luck.  Would it cause a conflict if I referenced my external one and had one in the /WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: To recap, you did drop `gson-1.6.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`? The `json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar` is not Gson.

Comment: Correct, I edited my post to correct that I am using Gson, not json-lib.  And yes, the Gson-1.6.jar exists in my /WEB-INF/lib as well as me workspace lib folder where I am referencing it from in the Build path

Comment: OK and *when* did you get this exception? During running some class with `main()` method as application inside the project? Or when running some JSP/Servlet code? I.e. what code exactly is using Gson and how exactly is it been executed? Note that a duplicate reference in build path is unnecessary. That lib should only exist in *Web App Libraries* which is auto-managed by Eclipse. Remove any manual references.

Comment: Ok, updated post at the bottom with a little more info.  Ok, if I just have it in the webapps/lib folder, I can reference it from there, but I just tried it without the build path reference and got compilation errors that the import could not be resolved

Comment: Ok, I think I know what happened, it's weird and probably a bug, but it seems when I put the jar in my /WEB-INF/lib folder, the project in eclipse didn't update even when I restarted eclipse.  After I right-click-updated the project, the library showed up and it compiles now - You are correct that the manual reference is not needed.  Thanks for your help an patience.

Comment: Thanks dude, this was a problem I kept running into often.

Comment: @BalusC why Gson imported though Maven does not work (scope :-compile / provided both) but it worked if manually kept GSON in web-INF/lib folder?? any idea?

Comment: @nick: because you need it during runtime when it's not provided by the target runtime.

Answer (score 23):

I faced same problem and tried above solutions but none of them worked for me. Then I tried following steps and the problem was solved:

- Go to the project properties.
- Go to Java Build Path option.
- Then add `*.jar` file as external jar.
- Then go to the order and export option and select the libraries and jars of the project.
- save the current changes and clean the project and run the project again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this method also worked for an Android project of mine as well!

Comment: Thank you so much.. As well, fixed the exact same error I suddenly started getting in my android project after a windows update.. 6 hours wasted until I read this... so pissed and tired.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting this error in an Android project. Your solution fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Click on `Deployment Assembly` ( right above `Java Build Path` that you show as active ) and make sure that you see json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar there.

Usually, you should add it to your build path and export it from your project.  Once it's exported you will see the WTP warning that it's not a part of the deployment.  Choose the `Quick Fix` option and add it to your deployment path.

Comment: Note that this section is only useful for external projects or libraries which are not dropped in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 4):

I was just having the same issue...

To resolve the problem (at least in my case) ensure you have included the lib folder in your bundle classpath:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
... 
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/gson-1.6.jar,
 .
...
```

Or if you want to include all jar's in the folder:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/
```

You will still need to place the jar files on the java build path as shown above.  Then your imported jar's should appear in the folder "Referenced Libraries"

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me working on an Eclipse Jetty project.

Answer (score 2):

Well for me the problem got resolved by adding the jars in my APACHE/TOMCAT/lib folder ! .

Comment: That makes the jar part of the classpath for *every* webapp you run in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

you can include maven dependency like below in your pom.xml file

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a Dynamic Wb App, after adding .jar to the java build path, you also have to do:

Project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add... -> Java Build Path Entries -> Next -> select the JAR file and click Finish. Apply and Close.

That helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when developing a KNIME Node/plugin in the Eclipse environment. The solution was not only to add the gson.jar as an externar JAR to the build path, it was also required to go to `plugin.xml`, then the Dependencies tab and add com.google.gson as a required plugin.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do the Quick fix in the Markers tab.

[image: Image Source metamug.com]

Reference: https://metamug.com/blog/eclipse-gson-class-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the above error when building and running inside Eclipse, where everything seemed to be fine, with the exception of this error. However, I discovered that a Maven build failed and that I needed to include Gson in my pom.xml. After fixing the pom.xml, everything fell into place.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone troubleshoot as I just wasted 30 minutes on this in Eclipse as a first time user - I had added the Gson jar to the 'ModulePath' section of build path libraries (alongside JRE system library). I needed to add it to the 'Classpath' to resolve this error.