# NoClassDefFoundError com/google/gson/Gson when trying to use gson in my project

Tags: java, gson, smartfoxserver

I have added gson to my java project, to be used as an extension for SmartFoxServer.
If I just add the following line:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

then when I export the extension, I get the following error in the SFS console:

> Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>   Message: com/google/gson/Gson

I have tried some solutions I found online, but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate any advice, or references to other JSON libraries which can do serialize/deserialize.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even

Answer (score 0):

Just copy Gson's jar to the directory of the extension in SFS.

If you want to share the jar in multiple extensions you could put it in `__lib__` dir.