# Not able to import and use correctly gson on javaEE web

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to change from netbeans to IntelliJ, so I'm a bit confused.

The project is simple, a java controller, connected from a Android device, and using plsql to make all the stuff on the database.

Everything works fine until we reach the first library, GSON, seems like I don't import it well, but I have used all the fixes that I have found on internet.

[image]

So when i make a search from my android device, I get this Exception.

[image: exception]

Also, the libraries don't show on the Libraries section

[I'm not able to put more than 2 links because of my rep, i will put in a comment below]

Thanks for everyone that tries to help this little noob!

Gretings, rudeboy.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/59099dde5e29e5f2ba387800181db73c // Libraries section // Library section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was solved on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even), and basically is putting all the libraries on WEB-INF/lib, and it solve it, hope this helps to anyone