# GsonBuilder will not be found

Tags: java, gson, xtext

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGLWE.jpg)How to resolve this Error?
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder

I'm trying to build a DSL in Xtext in Eclipse IDE and I install the Gson Jar to class-path this project but still does't work. Any one has the same Problem?

Comment: More context is needed. How do you add dependencies to your project? What kind of a project is it? Some code would come a long way. Meanwhile, perhaps this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even

Comment: this is case you should have added gson simply to the manifest as required bundle. and not as a jar to the project

Comment: @ChristianDietrich thanks, adding gson in manifest fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the missing `com.google.gson` bundle to the required bundles in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`